# Substitute part of a word in a string by the number of characters

Tags: r, regex

I have a long string that i'd like to match and replace certain parts of words with their respective character count.  I've tried using grouping to count the characters of a back-referenced group but when I call nchar it does not recognize the back-reference.

```
    gsub("\\b([a-z])([a-z]{1,})([a-z])",paste0("\\1",nchar("\\2"),"\\3"),"this is a test string")
    [1] "t2s is a t2t s2g"
```

The answer I would like to get:

```
    [1] "t2s is a t2t s4g"
```

Is there any way to count the number of characters in a group and replace using gsub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `gsubfn` to be able to manipulate capture groups:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> gsubfn("\\y([a-z])([a-z]+)([a-z])", function(x,y,z) paste0(x,nchar(y),z),"this is a test string")
[1] "t2s is a t2t s4g"
```

Note that `\y` is a word boundary (equivalent of `\b`) in  Tcl regex patterns (`gsubfn` uses Tcl regex library by default). You may also use `perl=TRUE` to use `\b`:

```
> gsubfn("\\b([a-z])([a-z]+)([a-z])", function(x,y,z) paste0(x,nchar(y),z),"this is a test string", perl=TRUE)
[1] "t2s is a t2t s4g"
```

Note that the capturing group values are passed to the anonynous replacement function via `x` (=`\1`), `y` (=`\2`) and `z` (=`\3`).

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can do the following:

```
x="This is a test string"
x=y
regmatches(y,b)<-Map(attr,b<-gregexpr("\\B([a-z]+)\\B",x),"match.length")
y
[1] "t2s is a t2t s4g"
```

You can decide to replace x directly, but you will loose its copy